# setarch i686 with builddep on fedora 35 can't find repositories

Tags: fedora, dnf

Want to install 32-bit build dependencies on Fedora 35, but fails, should this be possible? Is there a way to resolve it?

```
[root@fedora etc]# setarch i686 dnf builddep wine-devel
enabling fedora-source repository
enabling fedora-modular-source repository
enabling updates-source repository
enabling updates-modular-source repository
enabling rpmfusion-nonfree-nvidia-driver-source repository
enabling rpmfusion-nonfree-steam-source repository
Copr repo for PyCharm owned by phracek          176  B/s | 341  B     00:01    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'phracek-PyCharm':
  - Status code: 404 for https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/phracek/PyCharm/fedora-35-i386/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 52.44.175.77)
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'phracek-PyCharm': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
Fedora 35 - i386                                8.4 kB/s |  92 kB     00:10    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'fedora':
  - Status code: 404 for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-35&arch=i386 (IP: 152.19.134.142)
  - Status code: 404 for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-35&arch=i386 (IP: 8.43.85.67)
  - Status code: 404 for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-35&arch=i386 (IP: 38.145.60.21)
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'fedora': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Status code: 404 for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-35&arch=i386 (IP: 38.145.60.21)
[root@fedora etc]#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s not how you find 32-bit build dependencies with Fedora.

None of those repositories offer i386 versioned repos.  Using `setarch` like that makes DNF think you’re using it on a hypothetical i386 system, so when it does evaluates dnf variables it expands the `$basearch` in the repo files as i386 instead of x86_64. Fedora doesn’t offer a i386 repository.  It includes i686 builds of many of the libraries in the normal x86_64 repositories.

I suspect that you are using some methodology from Debian or other distro.  In Fedora, you install the 32-bit version of a package by running:

```
dnf install wine-devel.i686
```